# iOS unzip library and arm64 architecture

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to unzip .zip files on iOS.
I tried ZipArchive but got lots of linking warnings about undefined architectures for arm64.

I suppose I *could* remove the arm64 architecture from Xcode, but Apple must have started including it in iOS Xcode project templates by default for a reason, and I don't know enough about the ins and outs of that so don't particularly want to remove it in case it causes headaches in the future.

So I tried ZZipArchive which builds and runs but was failing to open the file, which when I traced through the code I found the failing function was called ZOPEN64(). Surprise surprise it has 64 in its name, can't be a coincidence.

I don't see the point in trying another iOS unzip library as they all seem to be wrappers around minizip etc. and thus will have the same fundamental issues.

Is anybody using an unzip library with iOS 7 AND the latest Xcode beta?

What are the consequences of removing the arm64 architecture out of the project if that's the only way for now to get unzip up and running?

Comment: Can't you just add arm64 to the ZipArchive build architectures?

Comment: arm64 is already in the project architecuture, that's what I'm saying that the unzip code can't handle its presence.

Comment: `zopen64()` relates to 64-bit file pointers, so it is a coincidence.

Comment: All the missing symbols imply that arm64 is set for your application, but not set for building ZipArchive.  How are you building ZipArchive itself?

Comment: The zipArchive is not a literal iOS library, sorry for using that term. It is just the source files so its not being build separately.

Comment: @trojanfoe, what might the reason be for zopen64 to fail to open a file when that file exists in the specified location?

Comment: No idea.  You should debug it and see.

Comment: Did you ever resolve your issue with this? I am having the same problem with any library using minizip complaining about arm64.  But, I think basically the c files have issues that the complier doesn't like.  But, it's not clear.  I'd happily use another unzip/zip tool for ios, but haven't found one.

Comment: I think I must have changed the source code for ziparchive and/or minZip to work. I searched for and didn't find zopen64 so I must have replaced it with something else. I have the source of my working versions of these these available if you need them

Comment: At this point all applications are required to include 64-bit support to be submitted to the App Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, the ramifications of removing arm64 from the architectures is that some classes of application will perform slower on devices with 64-bit capable processors (right now just iPhone 5s) than they would with arm64 builds enabled.

Note: at this point arm64 is required for all applications.

Comment: To update this answer. 64-bit support is now required.